# Don't know why valgrind gives me Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) error?

Tags: c, valgrind

My code below successfully converts a Binary search tree to a linked list however valgrind has been giving me "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" errors. Yet after looking at my code, I don't see where I have that?

```
ListNodePtr convertBSTtoLinkedList(TreeNodePtr root)
{
    ListNodePtr list,head;
    list = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    list->key = root->key;
    if (root->right != NULL)
    {
        list->next = convertBSTtoLinkedList(root->right);    //line 80
    }
    if (root->left != NULL)  
    {
    ListNodePtr tail;
    head = convertBSTtoLinkedList(root->left);   //line 85
    tail = head;
    while (tail->next != NULL) {        //Line 87
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    tail->next = list;
    return head;
    }
    return list;
}
```

This is my valgrind error, it repeats itself a few times.

```
==3076== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3076==    at 0x108AF2: convertBSTtoLinkedList (bst.c:87)
==3076==    by 0x108AC8: convertBSTtoLinkedList (bst.c:80)
==3076==    by 0x108ADD: convertBSTtoLinkedList (bst.c:85)
==3076==    by 0x108ADD: convertBSTtoLinkedList (bst.c:85)
==3076==    by 0x108ADD: convertBSTtoLinkedList (bst.c:85)
==3076==    by 0x108AC8: convertBSTtoLinkedList (bst.c:80)
==3076==    by 0x108AC8: convertBSTtoLinkedList (bst.c:80)
==3076==    by 0x108754: main (main_bst.c:28)
```

Comment: What is line 80 etc.

Comment: I have added comments.

Comment: Where is the NULL check for root ptr

Comment: list->key = root->key; did you check for root == NULL ?

Comment: Do you mean if a NULL root was passed to the function? If so, I added a check and it did not fix the errors.

Comment: in general, it is a poor programming practice to hide pointer types behind a `typedef`.

Comment: the posted code is missing any definition of `ListNodePtr`, `TreeNodePtr`.  So the posted code does not compile.  So we cannot reproduce the problem.  Please post those missing definitions

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc` gives you a pointer to uninitialized memory. So unless you set each member of your `ListNode` struct, trying to access that member later is a bad idea.

When your `convertBSTtoLinkedList` function processes any node of the BST which does not have a right child, it fails to set `next` on the created list node.  So the next time after that a higher level in the recursion attempts to find the end of the returned sublist, it walks to the end of the sublist, checks that uninitialized `next` pointer, and valgrind complains.

Comment: Ok I see, how can I fix this error in my situation?

Comment: Just add an `else` to your right child processing: `if (root->right != NULL) { ... } else { list->next = NULL; }`